# Right-click > New menu is overflowing with unnecessary options

Tags: pantheon-files

Recently the New... menu has overflown with useless options for new files, such as .bashrc, .Xauthority, or .steampath
Any suggestions for how to clear it out?
[image: right-click]

Here's my ~/Templates directory, there's no hidden files 
[image: ~/templates]

Comment: Somehow I think some files and foldres got in the wrong place. Can you put a screen shot with the contents of the ~/Templates folder?

Comment: @VladPop Sure, updated the question

Comment: Thanks for the added image. Normally, the 'New' menu lists the contents of the Templates folder. Since your Templates folder is almost empty, we need to see where those entries come from in your case. Can you locate the 'jack' and 'Guitar Pro6' folders? EDIT: look at the output of `tail ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, the `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR` variable's value.

Comment: OMG YES! Thank you :D

Comment: @BillO'Dwyer if you have the time, could you post an answer to the question with how you resolved the issue? That way, if anyone else has this issue, they can use your answer to solve it.

Comment: @DavidHewitt Done! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "New" list in the right-click menu draws from `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR` in `.config/user-dirs.dirs`.
Running the command `tail ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` showed that XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR was set as `$HOME` and hence was trying to use all the various dotfiles in the home directory as templates.

Amending the file so it says `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"` followed by a restart fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a comment here, as this has been an issue that I encountered recently.

If the Templates folder is Deleted, and the system is restarted, the config line changes to XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME".

By setting it to "$HOME/Templates", then creating a folder called Templates in the Home Directory, then restarting, fixed my issue.